# Import contacts from Windowlive/Hotmail from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hotmail, windows-live

I want to import contacts from window live/hotmail in my asp.net(c#) application.
If someone has idea, please guide me to do this.

Thanks,

Munish

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Windows Live Contacts API.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463982.aspx)

Edit: Seems to be deprecated. You can now try: [LiveSDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx#hotmail)